# Terraform: using exportCustomRoutes when setting peering connection

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, vpc-peering

I am trying to set-up a peering connection between 2 VPC networks.

One network (the transit one) configures static routes, and I would like to have those propagated to the peered network.

Here's an example:

```
...

data "google_compute_network" "transit-network" {
  project       = var.transit_project_id
  name = var.transit_network
}

resource "google_compute_network_peering" "to-transit" {
  name = "${var.project}-transit"
  network = "${google_compute_network.vpc_network.self_link}"
  peer_network = data.google_compute_network.transit-network.self_link
}

resource "google_compute_network_peering" "from-transit" {
  name = "transit-${var.project}"
  network = data.google_compute_network.transit-network.self_link
  peer_network = "${google_compute_network.vpc_network.self_link}"
}

...
```

I know that this is simply through the GCP console, but, I can't find a way to do it through terraform.

From the API it seems that is by using the field `peering.exchangeSubnetRoutes`

**EDIT**:
I have found the solution using the `google-beta` provider:

```
resource "google_compute_network_peering" "to-transit" {
  name = "${var.project}-transit"
  provider = "google-beta"
  network = "${google_compute_network.vpc_network.self_link}"
  peer_network = data.google_compute_network.transit-network.self_link
  import_custom_routes = true
}

resource "google_compute_network_peering" "from-transit" {
  name = "transit-${var.project}"
  provider = "google-beta"
  network = data.google_compute_network.transit-network.self_link
  peer_network = "${google_compute_network.vpc_network.self_link}"
  export_custom_routes = true
}
```

Using the `beta` provider I can specify `import_custom_routes` and `export_custom_routes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks! I've checked your solution on my project and it works for me with a slightly changed syntax:

```
resource "google_compute_network_peering" "vpc-network-to-transit-network" {
  provider             = google-beta
  name                 = "vpc-network-to-transit-network"
  network              = google_compute_network.vpc-network.self_link
  peer_network         = google_compute_network.transit-network.self_link 
  import_custom_routes = true
}

resource "google_compute_network_peering" "transit-network-to-vpc-network" {
  provider             = google-beta
  name                 = "transit-network-to-vpc-network"
  network              = google_compute_network.transit-network.self_link
  peer_network         = google_compute_network.vpc-network.self_link
  export_custom_routes = true
}
```

and

```
$ gcloud compute networks peerings list
NAME                            NETWORK          PEER_PROJECT  PEER_NETWORK     PEER_MTU  IMPORT_CUSTOM_ROUTES  EXPORT_CUSTOM_ROUTES  STATE   STATE_DETAILS
transit-network-to-vpc-network  transit-network  test-prj      vpc-network                False                 True                  ACTIVE  [2020-11-13T02:05:12.111-08:00]: Connected.
vpc-network-to-transit-network  vpc-network      test-prj      transit-network            True                  False                 ACTIVE  [2020-11-13T02:05:29.387-08:00]: Connected.
```

I used current version of Terraform:

```
$ terraform version
Terraform v0.13.5
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google v3.5.0
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google-beta v3.47.0
```